# Some google compute engine ports are closed

Tags: google-compute-engine, firewall

I've been trying to open a port using both the gcloud interface and the UI for Google Compute engine. There are other ports I've opened successfully a while ago, but now nothing new seems to take. According to gcloud describe, my instance has these tags assigned

```
tags:
  items:
  - http-server
  - https-server
  - push-server
  - redis-server
  - redis-server-prod
```

and these firewall rules are correctly set both in gc an UI

```
push-server             default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:3000 push-server
redis-server            default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:6395 redis-server
redis-server-prod       default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:6391 redis-server-prod
```

Both 6395 and 6391 are open, but 3000 is not. It's nothing specific to 3000, because no other ports work either. I'd appreciate any tips on how to troubleshoot this as I'm completely out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour this mysteriously became unblocked. I was using the same port tester each time.

http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

There must be some kind of delay between setting the firewall and it taking effect.